# Which version of node_modules are needed by Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

The front-end of the application I'm working on was written in *Angular JS*.  I am working on migrating the application to **Angular 14**.  When I create a new *Angular* application outside of my project workspace, I see that it creates a **node_modules** folder.  There is also a **node_modules** directory in my current application.  I'm guessing that, in order to use Angular within my application, I'm going to need to copy all of **node_modules** from my skeleton project into my existing project in order for **Angular** to work properly?

Comment: I wouldn't make a copy since you're switching from AngularJS to Angular. If you don't recall installing anything specific with npm you should be good to go. If there are packages you installed in the AngularJS app, just reinstall them in the Angular app with npm install.

Comment: Thank you!  That will make things a lot easier!